# PHP Warning on Asset Upload: PelInvalidDataException

Tags: assets, error-message, php, upload

I have a front-end form to upload image files, which works 100% perfectly most of the time. However, I've noticed with larger sized images, I'll get a PHP error saying:

```
PHP warning
include(pathToCraft/craft/app/vendor/lsolesen/pel/src/PelInvalidDataException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue on my end or Craft. Should I be expirementing which file size starts causing this and restricting uploads from surpassing that limit in the plugin before saving entry?

Comment: Yeah, you may want to do a few tests and try to narrow down the file size threshold. The error message doesn't directly indicate a size issue, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Also probably worth swapping from GD => Imagick (or visa-versa) to see if it's your underlying image processing library that's choking.